# Neo4j enterprise cluster master not fully utilizing CPU

Tags: neo4j, cpu, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j-4

We have a Neo4j v3.0.4 Enterprise cluster running on a machine in AWS with 16 cores and when we issue a lot of requests to it, it seems to only utilize at most ~40% of the CPU (when looking on the box using `htop` it only seems to utilize 6 cores?). Disk + network IO on said box all look negligible during the test.

Screen cap of CPU profile - the flat part is when we hit it with load:

[image]

Requests are routed to the DB via a cluster of Spring Boot apps using Spring Data Neo4j 4 and from our investigations it does not look like those servers are forming any bottlenecks, from a memory, CPU, and network IO POV.

We currently are NOT using Bolt, nor are we using causal clustering; however we are planning on moving towards both. In the interim though, is there anything that may cause this type of behavior? Could our DB be misconfigured? Could this be a JVM level problem?

Any advice is much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: An update for anyone interested - never got to the bottom of this; we ended up completing our migration to 3.3.x and this CPU issue seems to have gone away.